# Cargar dni sin duplicados con struct C

Tags: c, struct, busqueda

### **PROGRAMA EN C**

Tengo problemas con la funcion de busqueda secuancial dentro de un struct, si alguien me podria ayudar estaria agradecido, muchas gracias!!

Creo que tendría que cambiar los parametros de la funcion de busqueda secuencial para que tome un struct, pero no se como.

---

**Este es el ejercicio pedido.**

> Se sabe que como máximo en una comisión de Elementos de Programación hay 80 alumnos.
>    De cada alumno se conoce:
>
> • Número de DNI (entero)
>
> • Apellido y Nombre (80 caracteres)
>
> • Nota1, Nota2 (entero)
>
> • Nota Promedio (real, calculado según Nota1 y Nota2)
>
> Se solicita:
>
> **a.** Declarar un tipo de dato que contenga la información del alumno.
>
> **b.** Declarar un vector de estructuras del tipo de dato creado en el punto a.
>
> **c.** Cargar en un vector de estructuras, los datos referentes a los alumnos de la comisión, esta información termina con DNI igual al 0. Función INGRESO.
>
> **d.** Indicar cuántos alumnos aprobaron (ambos parciales con nota >= 4 y cuántos reprobaron la materia. Función RESULTADO.
>
> **e.** Informar los datos de los alumnos de (DNI – Apellido y Nombre – Nota Promedio) de los alumnos. PROMOCIONADOS (ambas notas >= 7). Función INFORME_PROMO.

---

**Cabecera:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define CONST 3

struct ALUMNO{
    int dni, nota1, nota2;
    char apellido_nombre[81];
    float promedio;
};

int INGRESO(struct ALUMNO[], int);
void RESULTADO(struct ALUMNO[], int);
void INFORME_PROMO(struct ALUMNO[], int);
```

**Funcion de busqueda:**

> ```
> int busquedaSecuencial(int[], int, int);
> ```

```
int main(){
    struct ALUMNO alumnos[CONST];
    int cantidad=0;

    cantidad= INGRESO(alumnos, CONST);
    RESULTADO(alumnos, cantidad);

    printf("\n\nAlumnos promocionados:\n");
    INFORME_PROMO(alumnos, cantidad);


    getch();
}

int INGRESO(struct ALUMNO v[], int max){
    int i=0;
    struct ALUMNO vect[max];

    printf("Ingrese DNI del alumno: ");
    scanf("%d", &v[i].dni);

    if(v[i].dni<0){
        do{
            printf("Numero erroneo, vuelva a ingresar: ");
            scanf("%d", &v[i].dni);
        }while(v[i].dni<0);
    }

    while(v[i].dni != 0 && i<max){
        printf("Ingrese apellido y nombre: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(v[i].apellido_nombre);

        printf("Ingrese nota 1: ");
        scanf("%d", &v[i].nota1);
        if(v[i].nota1<=0 || v[i].nota1>10){
            do{
                printf("Numero erroneo, vuelva a ingresar: ");
                scanf("%d", &v[i].nota1);
            }while(v[i].nota1<=0 || v[i].nota1>10);
        }

        printf("Ingrese nota 2: ");
        scanf("%d", &v[i].nota2);
        if(v[i].nota2<=0 || v[i].nota2>10){
            do{
                printf("Numero erroneo, vuelva a ingresar: ");
                scanf("%d", &v[i].nota2);
            }while(v[i].nota1<=0 || v[i].nota2>10);
        }

        v[i].promedio= (v[i].nota1+v[i].nota2)/2.;

        i++;

        printf("\nIngrese DNI del alumno: ");
        scanf("%d", &v[i].dni);
```

**Utilizacion de Busqueda Secuencial dentro de una funcion:**

> ```
>         if(busquedaSecuencial(v.dni, i, v[i].dni) != -1){
>             do{
>                 printf("Dni repetido, vuelva a ingresar: ");
>                 scanf("%d", v[i].dni);
>             } while(busquedaSecuencial(v.dni, i, v[i].dni) != -1);
>         }
> ```

Resto del codigo:

```
        if(v[i].dni<0){
            do{
                printf("Numero erroneo, vuelva a ingresar: ");
                scanf("%d", &v[i].dni);
            }while(v[i].dni<0);
        }
    }

    return i;
}

void RESULTADO(struct ALUMNO v[], int max){
    int i=0, aprobaron=0, desaprobaron=0;

    for(i=0; i<max; i++){
        if(v[i].promedio>=4){
            aprobaron++;
        }
        else{
            desaprobaron++;
        }
    }

    printf("\nCantidad de alumnos aprobados: %d\n", aprobaron);
    printf("Cantidad de alumnos desaprobados: %d\n", desaprobaron);
}

void INFORME_PROMO(struct ALUMNO v[], int max){
    int i=0;

    for(i=0; i<max; i++){
        if(v[i].promedio>=7){
            printf("DNI: %d\n", v[i].dni);
            printf("Apellido y nombre: ");
            puts(v[i].apellido_nombre);
            printf("Nota promedio: %.2f\n\n", v[i].promedio);
        }
    }
}
void RESULTADO(struct ALUMNO[], int, int, int);
```

**Funcion de busqueda secuencial:**

```
int busquedaSecuencial(int v[], int max, int dato){
    int i=0, pos=-1;

    for(i=0; i<max; i++){
        if(dato==v[i]){
            pos=i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return pos;
}
```

Comment: Y donde tienes el problema exactamente? En cual de las ciento y pico líneas de código?

Comment: Todo este código que has subido no sirve para nada porque te falta lo más importante. Si te falla la llamada a la función `busquedaSecuencial`, al menos deberías poner el código donde haces esa llamada. Según dices, la llamada es así: `if(busquedaSecuencial(v.dni, i, v[i].dni)`, pero eso no cuadra porque en ese punto `v` parece ser una estructura que tiene un campo `dni` pero también es un array de estructuras... A ver cómo se come eso, que la misma variable sean varias cosas totalmente diferentes. Con la información que has subido es imposible ayudarte.